# python -- multiprocessing.dummy pool feature to imporve query execution time

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have an oracle query which returns me around 3 million rows which looks something like this:

```
select key from table;---just one column
```

I am trying to get this executed in parallel using the pool object from  multithreading.dummy module in python

```
import threading
local = threading.local()

def execute_query:
    if not hasattr(local, 'db'):
         local.db = params.get('conn')
         cursor = local.db.cursor()
         cursor.execute(params.get('sql'))
         return cursor.fetchall()
```

And, to get the above mentioned oracle query executed in parallel I am doing:

```
def __call__(self):
    pool = Pool(10)
    data = pool.apply(execute_query, [{ 'conn' :   self._connection, 'sql': self._sql }])

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I got to know that the `apply method` of the `pool object` executes the passed function in only one of the worker threads.

Is there any way that I can get this `execute_query` executed among multiple threads to improve the performance?

Comment: Why do you use ` multithreading.dummy` if you want to use `multiprocessing`? Reread about it: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool

Comment: Spawning processes involves more overhead than spawning threads plus I would want to make use of the apply() and map() methods of the pool object. multiprocessing.dummy replicates the API of multiprocessing but is no more than a wrapper around the threading module.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: I am trying to get this executed in parallel.

```
apply(func[, args[, kwds]])

Call func with arguments args and keyword arguments kwds.
It blocks until the result is ready.
Given this blocks, apply_async() is better suited for performing work in parallel.
Additionally, func is only executed in one of the workers of the pool.
```